# Can you change a variable in a class based of another class name?

Tags: html, css

First of all I don't have access to the HTML code and I don't want to use JavaScrip for this. But here's my problem: The website has a way to change profile colors. To do this, the div that contains all elements that are to change the color is given an additional class name (e.g. "red"). The existing css code then adjusts the color variable and you can then use this variable inside the "red" class. However, the element for which I want to change the color is completely outside of these classes. Is there a way to check the class name of a div and if the class of that div is "red" then change the properties of another class.

So basically like an if condition: If the name of a class is "red", or if a class with the name "red" exists, then change the properties of class xy

I hope it was somehow understandable. I'm also very very new to programming.

Thanks

```
OLD HTML (Refer to new)
<div class="user red"> /*This color value changes depending of the profile color*/
   <a class="title"> Text in red </a>
</div>

<div class="menu">
   <a class="dropdown"> Text that should also be red </a> /*This text should change with the same variable*/
</div>
```

```
NEW HTML
<body>
    <div>
       <div>
          <div class="user red"> /*This color value changes depending of the profile color*/
             <a class="title"> Text in red </a>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
 
    <div class="menu">
       <a class="dropdown"> Text that should also be red </a> /*This text should change with the same variable*/
    </div>
 </body>
```

```
CSS
.user.red {
    --color-blue: 218,65,39;
}
.user.green {
    --color-blue: 37, 204, 81;
}

.title {
   color: rgb(var(--color-blue));
}
```

I want something like this:

```
CSS
[if any class with name "red"]
   .dropdown {
      color: 218,65,39;
   }

[if any class with name "green"]
   .dropdown {
      color: 37, 204, 81;
   }
```

Or something like this:

```
CSS
.user.red && .menu { /*This gets only applied when it can be applied to both. If not (because there is no class with name "red") it shouldn't be applied*/
   --color-blue: 218,65,39;
}

.dropdown {
   color: rgb(var(--color-blue));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the type of HTML structure you have shown, yes it can be done:

```html
<div class="user red"> /*This color value changes depending of the profile color*/
  <a class="title"> Text in red </a>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <a class="dropdown"> Text that should also be red </a> /*This text should change with the same variable*/
</div>
<style>
  .user.red {
    --color-blue: 218, 65, 39;
  }
  
  .user.green {
    --color-blue: 37, 204, 81;
  }
  
  .title {
    color: rgb(var(--color-blue));
  }
  
  .user.red~.menu .dropdown {
    color: rgb(218, 65, 39);
  }
  
  .user.green~.menu .dropdown {
    color: rgb(37, 204, 81);
  }
</style>
```

However, note the caveat.

The above snippet works because the div with class red is on the 'same level' i.e. is a preceding sibling of the div with class menu.

If the class red were on the anchor (a) element this would not work.

UPDATE - a new HTML structure was posted.
This snippet is very general - it is taking the 'if any element has class red/green' at face value and it looking at all the descendants of the body element to see whether they have red/green class.

You may want to make this a bit more specific, depends on exactly what structure you are dealing with.

Note: :has has good support amongst the major browsers except for Firefox at the moment (May 2023). FF requires a flag to be set.

```css
.user.red {
  --color-blue: 218, 65, 39;
}

.user.green {
  --color-blue: 37, 204, 81;
}

.title {
  color: rgb(var(--color-blue));
}


/*[if any class with name "red"]*/

body:has( *.red) .dropdown {
  color: rgb(218, 65, 39);
}


/*[if any class with name "green"]*/

body:has( *.green) .dropdown {
  color: rgb(37, 204, 81);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div class="user red"> /*This color value changes depending of the profile color*/
        <a class="title"> Text in red </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="menu">
    <a class="dropdown"> Text that should also be red </a> /*This text should change with the same variable*/
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Unfortunately, the two classes are not on the same level. As you announced, it didn't work. Nevertheless, thank you very much for the effort, I appreciate it alot.

Comment: In that case could you provide code which has the actual structure? It may still be possible but the HTML structure is key.

Comment: Please put the code in your question. And please check it as at the moment it isn’t legal HTML.

Comment: Oh, I'am sorry, it should work now. I added it as (New HTML) above.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the new code.

Comment: Thank you so much! It finally works :)
To your note about FF. Did I understand correctly that native compatibility might come, but can be circumvented by turning on the right flags?

Comment: Yes. That’s correct.

Comment: Okay, than thanks so much for your help and time, I appreciate it alot. Have a wonderful day.

Answer (score 0):

just use your `.red` class on a parent element, when you define a CSS variable all the children would have access to that variable.

so if you have multiple colors on a single page use the `.red` on the specific parent `<div class='parent red'>`

if you have one color per page u can just add the class to the `<body class="red">`

> The place in the CSS hierarchy where you declare a CSS variable will
> determine its level of visibility throughout the lower levels of the
> hierarchy.
> -from: https://blog.logrocket.com/css-variables-scoping/

Edit: changed the demo to your specific use case.

```css
.red{
  --color-theme:red;
}
.green{
  --color-theme:green;
}
.user,.menu{
  color:var(--color-theme);
}
```

```html
<body class="red"> <!-- change this to green -->

<div class="user"> 
  <a class="title"> Text in red </a>
</div>

<div class="menu">
  <a class="dropdown"> Text that should also be red </a>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should add, that the class "red" and the class "menu" ar on diffrent "levels", so i can't use the "red" class as a parent for "menu" (I can't change the HTML code either). Does it still work? Or is there a way to make variables global with bare css?

Comment: @Matewoo just add the class "red" to a parent of both "menu" and "user" just like the demo above, you can add it to the <body> if you want to

Comment: it doesn't have to be a  direct parent, the body is the ancestor of them all

Comment: I'am sorry, I don't know how to add the class name without editing the HTML code. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I assume the issue is no longer a problem ? tell me if you still didn't solve it.

Comment: If you’re trying to say that I have to edit the HTML code to fix the problem it’s unfortunately not possible for me to fix it with your method.

Comment: so you can't just add the class to the body like this : <body class='red' >  ?

Comment: That’s correct. I am unable to edit the HTML code in any way. I am simply trying to inject CSS into an existing website.

Comment: so you're not creating new classes ?

Comment: No, unfortunately the only thing I am able to do is providing CSS to the HTML code above. No new classes or changing the HTML code.

Comment: Hi @Matewoo  If you are a beginner in coding what u are doing is a bit hard unless you are following a tutorial or course. It's a bit hard to help u if u can't edit any of your code so u can test it for yourself.

Comment: Hi! Are there any keywords I can search for, bc I don't know what to look for. I know that it's very unfortunate, that I can't edit the HTML code, but the website is not owned by yeah, so no changing HTML, only CSS :(

Comment: @Matewoo share the whole html and css related code and we'll help you

Comment: Hey Aj Zack, thanks for your time, with the help of another user I finally got it to work, so no more help is needed, but anyways a major thanks.